# Subclass variables with the same name of superclass ones

Tags: python, subclass

Is it possible for no override for happen? For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        A.__init__(self, name)
        self.name = name + "yes"
```

Is there any way for `self.name` in class B to be independent from that of Class A's, or is it mandatory to use different names?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  What you have here is valid code, unless you're asking whether _instances_ of class B can have two values for `self.name`.  The answer to that question is no.

Comment: @g.d.d.c That's exactly what I'm asking; whether or not an instance of class B could have its own name value while still preserving the name of its superclass. Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: newbie question on the OP's example: in B.__init__ he calls A.__init__ instead of what I expected, self.__init__ . The former sets the *class* variable name, correct? Then again, it should be the same unless an instance has a new definition of __init__... ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Prefixing a name with two underscores results in name mangling, which seems to be what you want.  for example

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print self.__name


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        A.__init__(self, name)
        self.__name = name + "yes"

    def print_name(self):
        print self.__name

    def print_super_name(self):
        print self._A__name #class name mangled into attribute
```

within the class definition, you can address `__name` normally (as in the `print_name` methods).  In subclasses, and anywhere else outside of the class definition, the name of the class is mangled into the attribute name with a preceding underscore.

```
b = B('so')
b._A__name = 'something'
b._B__name = 'something else'
```

in the code you posted, the subclass attribute will override the superclass's `name`, which is often what you'd want.  If you want them to be separate, but with the same variable name, use the underscores