# Python, the parent changes when using append list to change the child content

Tags: python, inheritance, append

I am trying to use append to add variables to a child in Python, while changing the list in child modifies the parent. Example code:

```
class parent:
    A=[1,2,3]

class child(parent):
     pass

child.A.append('new variable')
parent.A
```

the output is: [1, 2, 3, 'new variable']

while I was expecting to have: [1, 2, 3]
How can I edit the list in a child without altering the parent (assuming that I am not allowed to change the parent, so I cannot use instance)?

Comment: You can make the list an instance variable instead of a class variable.

Comment: Check the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927055/subclass-variables-with-the-same-name-of-superclass-ones

Comment: `A` doesn't exist in `child`'s `__dict__` attribute, so `child.A` resolves to `parent.A`.

Comment: No, it is just the problem with append. If I had a string instead of list, then it was independent

Comment: Yes; that is because there is nothing you can do to a string that modifies it in-place, you can only replace it. When you use `.append` on a list, it is the same object, only its contents have changed. By *assigning to* `child.A`, you do not replace the `parent.A`, but create a separate `A` attribute attached to the `child`.

Comment: @MostafaHas its because `.append` mutates the object. If you want the child class to not inherit the parent class attribute referring to the same object, then you will have to add that attribute to the child class, even just `A = Parent.A.copy()`. This isn't an issue with strings because `str` objects dont' expose any mutator methods like `.append`, so all methods return *new strings* wheras most list methods modify the list in-place

Answer (score 0):

It is basically problem of name mangling

class A:
def **init**(self, name):
self.__name = name

```
def print_name(self):
    print self.__name


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, name):
        A.__init__(self, name)
        self.__name = name + "yes"

    def print_name(self):
        print self.__name

    def print_super_name(self):
        print self._A__name #class name mangled into attribute
```

Check the answer given in below link
[Subclass variables with the same name of superclass ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927055/subclass-variables-with-the-same-name-of-superclass-ones)

Comment: I think this answer may have been intended for another question?

Comment: my understanding is that the question asked to separate parent and child variable.